# Why does 'AND' work here when 'OR' does not?

Tags: excel, vba

In my situation, the use of OR does not work, I have to use AND, and I'm not sure why.

```
Sub blah()
    If LCase(Environ("username")) <> "me" Or LCase(Environ("username")) <> "some other user" Then '''DOESN'T WORK
        Stop
    ElseIf LCase(Environ("username")) <> "me" And LCase(Environ("username")) <> "some other user" Then  '''WORKS
        Stop
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean in this context? it return `True` and you expect `False`?

Comment: OR returns false and I expect true, AND returns true and I expect false

Comment: That's not possible. `Environ("username")` cannot be both `"me"` and `"some other user"`: the `And` condition can only ever be `False`.

Comment: Is it equals or *doesn't* equal?

Comment: Sorry, just checked. it's does not equal

Comment: What is "the assumed use of OR"? Please explain what you are trying to accomplish with this code.

Comment: thanks for all the answers. The does not equal threw me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VBA `Or` doesn't work because when `Environ("username")` is *me*, it isn't *some other user* and vice versa.

You want to make sure that it isn't either of the possibilities so you need `And`.

Answer (score 7):

Your example is hard to understand, but you're probably just confused by the nature of the operators.

Think of truth tables; the result of an `Or` operation is `True` if at least one of the operands is `True`:

```
True Or True   => True
True Or False  => True
False Or True  => True
False Or False => False
```

Similarly, the result of an `And` operation is `True` if *both* operands are `True`:

```
True And True   => True
True And False  => False
False And True  => False
False And False => False
```

If it helps, you can visualize `Or` as a `+` (addition) and `And` as a `*` (multiplication) operation, with `False` being `0` and `True` being "not zero":

```
1 Or 1 => 1 + 1 => True
1 Or 0 => 1 + 0 => True
0 Or 1 => 0 + 1 => True
0 Or 0 => 0 + 0 => False

1 And 1 => 1 * 1 => True
1 And 0 => 1 * 0 => False
0 And 1 => 0 * 1 => False
0 And 0 => 0 * 0 => False
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down. I have to assume that `"me"` is your own username. The result of this test is:
`False, True, True`

```
Debug.Print LCase(Environ("username")) <> "me"
Debug.Print LCase(Environ("username")) <> "some other user"
Debug.Print LCase(Environ("username")) <> "me" Or LCase(Environ("username")) <> "some other user"
```

That is the expected behavior to me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be explained using [DeMorgan's laws](http://ice-web.cc.gatech.edu/ce21/1/static/JavaReview-RU/Conditionals/cDeMorgans.html). If we take:

```
If LCase(Environ("username")) <> "me" Or LCase(Environ("username")) <> "some other user" Then
```

then we can rewrite this by replacing the `<>` with `=` and then negating each term with `Not`:

```
If Not(LCase(Environ("username")) = "me") Or Not(LCase(Environ("username")) = "some other user") Then
```

Using DeMorgan's laws, we can take apply a single negation to the whole expression as long as we change the `Or` operator to an `And` operator:

```
If Not(LCase(Environ("username")) = "me" And LCase(Environ("username")) = "some other user") Then
```

It's impossible for `LCase(Environ("username")` to simultaneously equal two distinct values and thus the `And` condition will be False. Applying the `Not` operator means that the entire expression will always evaluate to True regardless of the value of "username"

---

For the corrected version using `And` instead of `Or` the steps are as follows:

```
If LCase(Environ("username")) <> "me" And LCase(Environ("username")) <> "some other user" Then
```

Change `<>` to `=` and apply `Not` operators:

```
If Not(LCase(Environ("username")) = "me") And Not(LCase(Environ("username")) = "some other user") Then
```

Apply DeMorgan's laws:

```
If Not(LCase(Environ("username")) = "me" Or LCase(Environ("username")) = "some other user") Then
```

Now, if the username is "me" or the username is "some other user" then the `Or` condition will evaluate to True and the `Not` operator will change that to False as required.

If the username is any other value then the `Or` condition will evaluate to False and the `Not` operator will change that to True as required